# How to setText of elements in JLabel array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, nullpointerexception, jlabel

I want to change the text displayed on JLabels within an array after instantiation. 
I currently get a java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Frame");

        JLabel[] labelArray = new JLabel[2];

        labelArray[0].setText("a");
        labelArray[1].setText("b");

        frame.add(labelArray[0]);
        frame.add(labelArray[1]);

        frame.setSize(350, 200); // width=350, height=200
        frame.setVisible(true); // Display the frame
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating the array but their are no values in it. So if you access `labelArray[0]` it would return null.

You should set the values of the array:

```
JLabel[] labelArray = new JLabel[2];
labelArray[0] = new JLabel("someText");
labelArray[1] = new JLabel("someText");
```

Now you can access the labels without the NullPointer Exceptions.